# Easy PHP Calendar

Tags: php, html

I would like make easy PHP Calendar.
For example: [blog.tiger.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/gcalendar.png](http://blog.tiger.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/gcalendar.png)
But only for one day, for this example: 6/26.

I have:

```
$hours = range(1, 24);
```

and:

show this hours with a html table:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($hours as $hour){ ?>
  <tr><td><?php echo $hour ?> </td></tr> 
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

and I have:

```
$reservations = array(array('name' => 'first reservation for user Paul', 'from' => 6, 'to' => 8),
                     array('name' => 'second reservation for my group', 'from' => 11, 'to' => 14)  );
```

But I don't know how to add `$reservations` to my foreach with `$hours`. If is reservation I would like red background for hours from 6 to 8 and from 11 to 14 and between from 6 and 8 showing text from index name, and between 11 and 14 show text from index name. Best way this is use rowspan for this text, but how?

Comment: An image of the google calendar doesnt comply with a `simple calendar`. Can there be more then one event on a specific hour or is it just reserved or not?

Comment: You probably want hours to be form 0 to 23, not 1 to 24. In your `foreach($hours as $hour)` you need to loop over `$reservations` and check if the reservation matches the hour, if so, add a `<td>` and use HTML (or CSS) to colour the background. If not, you still need an emoty `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting up an array of 'busy hours', something like this:

(edited to include text)

```
<?php 
$busyhours = array;
foreach ( $reservations as $reservation ) {
    $hours = $reservation['to'] - $reservation['from'];
    while ($hours) {
        $busyhours[] = $reservation['to'] + $hours;
        $hours--;
    }
    $busyhours[$reservation['to']] = $reservation['name']; //made the busy hour the key.
}
?>

<table>
    <?php foreach($hours as $hour){ ?>
        <tr><!-- changed in_array() to array_key_exists b/c of above change -->
            <td <?php if ( array_key_exists($hour, $busyhours) ) { echo "class='red-bg'"; } ?> >
                <?php 
                    echo $hour; 
                    echo "<p>" . $busyhours[$hour] . "</p>";
                ?> 
            </td>
        </tr> 
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```